# SVG animation doesn't follow the defined path

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I am working on a svg animation in which the animation has to trace the path which i defined previously,but the intial position of the animation when its starts seems to get displaced to another place but it still traces the same path but on different co-ordinates.
I want to the animation to follow along the path which is defined.

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <path id="motionPath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0,342.8c0,0,138.4-1.5,221.8-50.1c0,0,150.2-87.8,344.6-28.3c16.5,5.1,31.7,9.7,45.5,13.9"/>
  <path id="motion" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="st0" d="M0,379.8c0,0,154.4-114.9,223.4-71.6s381.4,29.7,388.6-24.3"/>
  
  <g id="car"   transform="translate(0, 0)">
      <path id="note" d="M248.8,306.8c0,0-24-7-28.5,11c0,0-3,16,21,16.5c0,0,19.5,2.3,18.5-28.8s0-61.2,0-61.2s42,9,19,31.5
 c0,0,17-1,13.5-23c0,0-7.5-20-43-22L248.8,306.8z"/>
 <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</g>

 <g id="car1"   transform="translate(0, 0)">
      <path id="note" d="M248.8,306.8c0,0-24-7-28.5,11c0,0-3,16,21,16.5c0,0,19.5,2.3,18.5-28.8s0-61.2,0-61.2s42,9,19,31.5
 c0,0,17-1,13.5-23c0,0-7.5-20-43-22L248.8,306.8z"/>
 <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</g>
   


     <animateMotion 
           xlink:href="#car1"
           dur="3s"
          begin="click"
           fill="freeze"
            repeatCount="indefinite"
             >
    <mpath xlink:href="#motion" />
  </animateMotion>


  <animateMotion 
           xlink:href="#car"
           dur="3s"
          begin="click"
           fill="freeze"
            repeatCount="indefinite"
             >
    <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath" />
  </animateMotion>
</svg>
```

Comment: jsFiddle-https://jsfiddle.net/9hyesqov/

Comment: @RobertLongson It felt way too cluttery when added inside the question. I thought this way provided more legibility.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the edit. Can you help me with my issue ?

Comment: You've not drawn your shapes at the start of the path so they are rather bound to follow at an offset. Also the paths don't start at 0,0 so they immediately apply that offset.

Comment: @RobertLongson I actually drew the notes and the paths on seperate illustrator file and then exported it as svg

Comment: @RobertLongson If i apply translate property still it is displaced by few pixels